# React Native Application not showing images on Android Build

Tags: android, react-native

My RN app is not showing images when built for android, I have it built for IOS and it works perfectly then, however when I load the images in the android version, the app will throw a could not open file error.

I tried to modify the folder structure as found in various resources online however the error will still persist, what is odd is that I have some local html files which I'm loading as well located near the images, however the HTML will load perfectly well.

Here's the code which determines the URI

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

function BaseURI(){

    let baseURI = './assets/';

    if (Platform.OS === 'android')
    {
        baseURI = 'file:///android_asset/';
    }

    return baseURI;
}

function AssetURI(url){
    return BaseURI() + url;
}

export {BaseURI, AssetURI}
```

Lets say I'm loading the image I would use this //logo_uri = 'file:///android_asset/resources/buttons/Logo.png';

[image]

Comment: Send code examples.  Hard to say without an example.

Comment: added code to example

Answer (score 0):

Update this

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android')
{
    baseURI = 'file:///android_asset/';
}
```

To

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android')
{
    baseURI = 'file:///android_asset/';
}
else {
    baseURI = 'file://android_asset/';
}
```

To reference files in iOS, it's 2 forward slashes and 3 for Android.